# How to query :host property of css

Tags: css, selenium, webdriver, background-color, value-of-css-property

I have an element I'm querying to get the CSS properties in Selenium. The actual background colour is white, but whenever I query to get the background-color I do get #000000. The app is build with Ionic.

I inspect using Chrome DevTools and found out that the `--background: #fff;` is actually what I need. I don't know how to query the host property, as it seems foreign to me.

```
:host {
    --background: #fff;
    --color: #000;
    --padding-top: 0px;
    --padding-bottom: 0px;
    --padding-start: 0px;
    --padding-end: 0px;
    --keyboard-offset: 0px;
    --offset-top: 0px;
    --offset-bottom: 0px;
    --overflow: auto;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: var(--ion-font-family,inherit);
    contain: size style;
    flex: 1 1 0%;
    margin: 0px !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
}
```

This code is  working as expected but it does not get the effective background color

```
String bgColor = Color.fromString(webElement.getCssValue("background-color")).asHex();
```

Answer (score 0):

This will search through your stylesheet rules and log out the variable --background in :host. Tweak to suit.

```
  for(const sheet of document.styleSheets) {
    for(const rule of sheet.rules) {
      if(rule.selectorText==":host") {
        console.log(rule.style.getPropertyValue('--background'));
      }
    }
  }
```